# Mysql stored procedure to create user and grant privileges based on one of parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addUser`(IN p_Name varchar(100), IN p_Passw varchar(200),
IN p_Tipo varchar(3), IN p_Email varchar(200))
BEGIN
    SET @sql := CONCAT('CREATE USER \'', p_Name, '\'@\'localhost\'', ' IDENTIFIED BY \'', p_Passw, '\'');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    INSERT INTO Utilizador (EmailUtilizador, NomeUtilizador,TipoUtilizador) VALUES (p_Email,p_Name,p_Tipo);
    CASE
    WHEN p_Tipo = 'ADM' THEN GRANT appadmin TO p_Name@'localhost';
    WHEN p_Tipo = 'SEG' THEN GRANT seguranca TO p_Name@'localhost';
    WHEN p_Tipo = 'CSG' THEN GRANT chefeseguranca TO p_Name@'localhost';
    WHEN p_Tipo = 'DIR' THEN GRANT diretor TO p_Name@'localhost';
    WHEN p_Tipo = 'SEN' THEN GRANT sensor TO p_Name@'localhost';
    END CASE;
END
```

As far as I've tested everything works until we reach the case, but I'm having some problems making case when work, how can I grant privileges based on my p_Tipo parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt anyone will need this, but i figured it out, all i had to do was kind of mirror the 1st part, ended up looking like this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addUser`(IN p_Name varchar(100), IN p_Passw varchar(200),
IN p_Tipo varchar(3), IN p_Email varchar(200))
BEGIN
    SET @sql := CONCAT('CREATE USER \'', p_Name, '\'@\'localhost\'', ' IDENTIFIED BY \'', p_Passw, '\'');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    INSERT INTO Utilizador (EmailUtilizador, NomeUtilizador,TipoUtilizador) VALUES (p_Email,p_Name,p_Tipo);
    CASE
        WHEN p_Tipo = 'ADM' THEN SET @perm := concat('GRANT appadmin TO \'',p_Name,'\'@\'localhost\'');
        WHEN p_Tipo = 'SEG' THEN SET @perm := concat('GRANT seguranca TO \'',p_Name,'\'@\'localhost\'');
        WHEN p_Tipo = 'CSG' THEN SET @perm := concat('GRANT chefeseguranca TO \'',p_Name,'\'@\'localhost\'');
        WHEN p_Tipo = 'DIR' THEN SET @perm := concat('GRANT diretor TO \'',p_Name,'\'@\'localhost\'');
        WHEN p_Tipo = 'SEN' THEN SET @perm := concat('GRANT sensor TO \'',p_Name,'\'@\'localhost\'');
    END CASE;
    PREPARE grnt FROM @perm;
    EXECUTE grnt;
END
```